# Popup close button not closing the popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, frontend

I've been working on this popup that displays upon the webpage loading. It shows up, but for some reason the close button does not work. I'm a little inexperienced with front end, but I've been reading up on some tutorials and it seems if you wanna make something close you use the class "close." So I tried that, but to no success.

Note: sorry if this was not clear before, I think someone misinterpretted my question and edited it to reflect so but the popup is not the tooltipster! I have removed that from the code to make it more clear. The popup is done through #ac-wrapper and #popup in style and the function PopUp() in the script thats in my html file

Here's what I have.

```js
function PopUp() {
  document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 1001;
}

#popup {
  display: "none";
  width: 555px;
  height: 375px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper">
  <div id="popup">
    <center>
      <h3> welcome to my website</h3>
      <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `tooltipster` is ancient. Also you are using a really really old jQuery. Perhaps find a newer popup ?

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.heteroclito.fr/modules/tooltipster/#demos): _hideOnClick
boolean If true, the tooltip will close if its origin is clicked. This option only applies when 'trigger' is 'hover' and 'autoClose' is false. Default: false_

Comment: the popup isnt the tooltipster, thats something separate. please see my edited post

Comment: Hello? Did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple:

```js
function PopUp() {
  document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "block";
}


document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click",()=> document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display='none');
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 1001;
}

#popup {
  display: "none";
  width: 555px;
  height: 375px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper">
  <div id="popup">
    <center>
      <h3> welcome to my website</h3>
      <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works as expected here. Did you run the snippet?

Comment: ya, thats odd that the snippet works but my program doesnt. will experiment with it, thank you!